# Shrink and expand table width as screen width changes

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-table, screen-size

I want to be able to shrink the width of my table as the screen width decreases and expand the width of the table when the screen width increases.
I know that I can use `@media()` in both CSS and JavaScript but I'm trying to find a simpler way to do this.
The current issue that I am having is that another div outside of the parent div of my table is overlapping the table when the screen width shrinks.

Here is the CSS for my table:

```
#course_table {
  margin: auto;
  font-family: "Lato","Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  padding: 12px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  border-radius: 4px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: A more simple way than using media queries?  By what guideline are you defining "simple"?

Comment: @MisterJojo, how would I go about doing that?

Comment: @Taplar, by simple I mean just adding some attributes to `#course_table` in CSS without needing to add multiple variations for multiple media queries.

Comment: table size depend on the sum of each column size. global size on table element is ignored;; ifyou you want to change the table size you have to change each column size, more easy to do with em unit

Comment: can you give me an example in code of how this works because I've never had to use em units before.

Comment: vw unit is fine too, for full width of page

Comment: Once again I need an example of how to do this because I tried using vw (which I've never had to use before) and while it did shrink the table, it did not continue to shrink as the screen width decreased.

Comment: is it an order ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sample code with **vw** unit

```css
body { margin: 0;}
* { box-sizing: border-box; }

Table { border-collapse: collapse; margin: 0;   }
td    { border: 1px solid grey; padding: 2px 10px; }
thead { background-color: turquoise;}

table tr td:nth-child(1) { width: 30vw }
table tr td:nth-child(2) { width: 10vw }
table tr td:nth-child(3) { width: 60vw }
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr><td>A</td><td>B</td><td>C</td></tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

PS: using magic words is not prohibited here...

Answer (score 0):

use width in uints of 'vw' i.e. view port width!

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_unit_vw

Comment: I tried vw, it shrinks the table but I need the width to shrink dynamically with the screen width shrinking, so I'm still getting overlapping issues.

Comment: give min-width to all columns / cells to avoid overlaping of one column's data with another, also you could give, work-break:break-all to all columns/ cells

Comment: what should the min-width be?

Comment: depends on you totally. depends on how responsive u want ur app to be.